# How to close a Zehon FTP connection

Tags: java, ftp

At one point in my code, i have to upload 70-80 files to a FTP server.

Best scenario would be to create a connection, upload 20 files, close it. Do this until all files are uploaded.
I tried a different connection per file... That was a disaster.

However, I cannot find any disconnect() or close() functions that would allow me to close the connection... Only thing I found was a static function closeCache()  which is only advised to be used before closing the software... So not really working for me...

And I am always getting a 'server closed connection' exception after uploading 25 files.

I possibly might not have a full understanding of this API.

```
public static boolean uploadFiles() {
    int count = 0;
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);
    try {
        if (!Tools.isListNullOrEmpty(xmlFilesToBeUploaded)) {
            for (File xmlFile : xmlFilesToBeUploaded) {
                if (count == MAX_FILES_PER_CONNECTION) {
                    count = 0;
                    ftpClient = null;
                    ftpClient = new FTPClient(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);
                }

                // "/" for root folder
                ftpClient.sendFile(xmlFile.getAbsolutePath(), "/");
                count++;
            }
        }
        xmlFilesToBeUploaded = null;
        if (!Tools.isListNullOrEmpty(imageFilesToBeUploaded)) {
            for (File imageFile : imageFilesToBeUploaded) {
                if (count == MAX_FILES_PER_CONNECTION) {
                    count = 0;
                    ftpClient = null;
                    ftpClient = new FTPClient(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);
                }

                // "/" for root folder
                ftpClient.sendFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), "/" + IMAGES_FOLDER);
                count++;
            }
        }
        imageFilesToBeUploaded = null;
        return true;
    } catch (FileTransferException e) {
        Log.error(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I used Apache Commons library which did the job I needed and is more flexible for development.